# R identify the variables which values sums a specific amount

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I have a df like that:

```
       Client.Code.      Invoice        Amount 
   1:      1004772    20170800563       3620.32
   2:      1005012    20171000389       52661.62
   3:      1005012    20171000466       14800.72
   4:      1004742    20171200022       5445.00
   5:      1004724    20171100426       26620.00
```

Then I get (for instance) a payment of 67462,34 by client 1005012. In this case is plain vanilla to know this payment is related with invoices 20171000389 and 20171000466, but sometimes it could be really hard.

I was wondering if there is any method in R to identificate variables which the sum of their amounts is equal to a given number, aplying the restriction that all the variable should be from the same client code.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you are re-describing the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There is no easy way to solve such a problem in the general case.

Comment: That is still clearly an optimization problem. It may seem "obvious" and trivial with only a few rows to check, in which case you are suggesting a per-client-id exhaustive search. The solution is technically "NP-hard". Especially when the OP says *"sometimes it could be really hard"*, that confirms that doing this in R can take a long time. (BTW: this is likely exacerbated by [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) with floating-point comparison, so to find the correct subset you'll need two inequality constraints.)

Comment: (I swear there was another comment here a moment ago ...)

Comment: Ok, I see, it´s easy to do it with excel´s solver, I´ll keep doing that way.

Comment: Álvaro, don't mistake what we are saying. This is not hard to implement in R using optimization functions, but it is hard to generalize since it is dynamic and NP-hard. Excel provides a gui for setting up basic optimization-like actions, but solving it programmatically will require a little work. A quick search finds https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adagio/versions/0.6.5/topics/knapsack.

Comment: In commercial practice accounting packages often allocate payments received against invoices not by trying to match the total against the sum of invoices but by distributing the payment against the earliest invoices first. What matters most is the overall account balance at a particular date and how much is outstanding for how long, which will not be a simple match of payments received against recent orders.

Answer (score 0):

This is a search in a tree which can be quite big (even when using pruning). 
In this context, pruning means that if you already have a value that is greater than the sum you want, it's not useful to continue searching in the branch.
You can implement this search like this:

```
library(data.tree)

find_solutions <- function(df, client.code, sum.value, print_tree = FALSE) {

  df_sub <- subset(df, Client.Code. == client.code)
  # Sorting makes pruning better
  df_sub <- df_sub[order(df_sub$Amount, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  n <- nrow(df_sub)
  max <- sum.value
  solutions <- list()

  grow_tree <- function(node) {

    id <- node$level
    if (id <= n) {          
      val <- node$value + df_sub$Amount[id]
      if (val == max) {
        solutions[[length(solutions) + 1]] <<- 
          c(which(node$path[-1] == "yes"), id)
        node$AddChild("yes", value = val)
      } else if (val < max) {
        grow_tree(node$AddChild("yes", value = val))
        grow_tree(node$AddChild("no", value = node$value))
      } else {
        grow_tree(node$AddChild("no", value = node$value))
      }
    }

    NULL
  }

  grow_tree(root <- Node$new(value = 0))

  if (print_tree) print(root, "value")

  lapply(solutions, function(ids) df_sub$Invoice[ids])
}
```

---

Tests:

```
# Your example data
df <- read.table(text = "       Client.Code.      Invoice        Amount 
   1:      1004772    20170800563       3620.32
           2:      1005012    20171000389       52661.62
           3:      1005012    20171000466       14800.72
           4:      1004742    20171200022       5445.00
           5:      1004724    20171100426       26620.00")


find_solutions(df, client.code = 1005012, sum.value = 67462.34, print_tree = TRUE)

df2 <- df
df2$Client.Code. = 1005012  
find_solutions(df2, client.code = 1005012, sum.value = 67462.34, print_tree = TRUE)
```